# location.href redirect page to given url instead of downloading the file on some browser

Tags: javascript

On some user's browser location.href is not downloading the file instead it redirect to the given url.

HTML code

`<a onclick="downloadFile("7632746786662232")" href="#">File</a>`

Javascript code

```
function downloadFile(id){
   location.href = "file.download?clientName="+$('#clientName').text()+"&id="+id;
}
```

Same code is working for most of the user but it is redirect to new url for an user.

Comment: `location.href` Set the URL of the current page

Comment: Why not use the [`download` attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLAnchorElement/download)?

Comment: not sure, may be related to this: https://superuser.com/questions/408243/prevent-chrome-from-automatically-opening-downloaded-pdf-and-image-files Chrome opening pdf and img files automatically post download

Comment: same code is working for all except one user's machine.

Comment: create a tag with href and dowload attributes. and click it ```const a = document.createElement('a'); a.setAttribute('href', link); a.setAttribute('download'); a.click(); ```